# What is an efficient way of running two queries using SqlQuerySpec against Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

What is the most efficient way to get multiple result sets from Cosmos Db?

For example I want to run the following 2 queries to get a range of readings between two dates and also get the closest reading to the start of the range:

```
    var query1 = $@"
                    SELECT TOP 1
                        n.Timestamp, 
                        n.Value 
                    FROM 
                        Readings AS n 
                    WHERE 
                        n.MeterCode = @meterCode AND 
                        n.Timestamp < @fromUtc 
                    ORDER BY
                        n.Timestamp DESC";

   var query2 = $@"
                    SELECT
                        n.Timestamp, 
                        n.Value 
                    FROM 
                        Readings AS n 
                    WHERE 
                        n.MeterCode = @meterCode AND 
                        n.Timestamp >= @fromUtc AND 
                        n.Timestamp <= @toUtc
                    ORDER BY
                        n.Timestamp ASC ";
```

I am currently executing 2 separate queries using syntax like this (where parameters1 is a SqlParametersCollection):

```
var querySpec1 = new SqlQuerySpec(query1, parameters1);
var docQuery1 = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Reading>(collectionUri, querySpec1).AsDocumentQuery();
while (docQuery.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var result = docQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Reading>().Result;
                // Do something with result
            }
```

Is there a way to achieve this using one query?  (For example in SQL you could use a UNION or LEAD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported in Cosmos DB. For some pairs of queries, you can rewrite via sub-queries to return the result in one query, but not with different ORDER BY clauses. You have to query separately - this can be done in parallel, without sacrificing E2E performance since Cosmos DB supports high concurrency.